# Difference between tokenized and normal text in Python NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, smt, moses

I am using the WordPunct Tokenizer to tokenize this sentence:

في_بيتنا كل شي لما تحتاجه يضيع ...ادور على شاحن فجأة يختفي ..لدرجة اني اسوي نفسي ادور شيء

My code is:

```
import re
import nltk
sentence= " في_بيتنا كل شي لما تحتاجه يضيع ...ادور على شاحن فجأة يختفي ..لدرجة اني اسوي نفسي ادور شيء"
wordsArray = nltk.tokenize.wordpunct_tokenize(sentence)
print " ".join(wordsArray)
```

I noticed that the printed output is the same as the input sentence, so why do use the tokenizer?
Also, would there be any difference creating a machine translation system (MOSES) using the token files or normal text files?

Comment: It's printing the input because you joined the tokens back together.  You would tokenize when you want to work with the words individually.

Comment: You might want to edit this question to emphasise the MT part of your question, if that's the most important part, or set up a second question to ask about using tokenized vs. untokenized texts in MT in general.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the tokeniser is a list of tokens (`wordsArray`). What you do is you join again the tokens in the list into one string with the command:

```
print " ".join(wordsArray)
```

Replace this with:

```
print wordsArray
```

Your second question regarding MOSES is not clear, please try to be more specific.